# Can't view, download, nor upload files on MobaXterm windows

Tags: ssh, mobaxterm

I connect to my university cluster on MobaXterm to submit jobs and when trying to download, upload, or open any files, they start but remain stuck at 0% progress

Its basically the same problem as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53602440/cant-upload-files).

But with all the features, upload, download, open file, and, also, none of the solutions worked for me. Changing to SCP didn't work, no problem with path file language.

MobaXterm log shows this after transfer begins:

```
[22:18.35.214]  (SSH-Browser) TDownUpForm.Timer1Timer  
[22:18.35.824]  (SSH-Browser) TDownUpForm.Timer1Timer
[22:18.36.434]  (SSH-Browser) TDownUpForm.Timer1Timer
[22:18.37.043]  (SSH-Browser) TDownUpForm.Timer1Timer
```

Keeps going until I cancel the transfer, no errors come up. Tried this on multiple different clusters, so it isn't a problem on their end.

Comment: Are able to SCP files from windows to that machine independent of MobaXTerm?  As in the SCP command built into windows?  Knowing that might be a good place to start.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas i succesfully transferred a file  by scp via cmd, so it seems that the problem is on Moba itself?

Comment: I hate to put it that way but yes.  The problem seems to lie somewhere on that end (as you already deduced).

Comment: Thanks. Thats sad, because it was the only one i was using for months. I've done clean uninstalls, reinstalls, checked the firewall and nothing happens.

Comment: Have you tried [WinScp](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php)?  I actually prefer it for some tasks.